# loop/recursion to handle hierarchical structures in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I was wondering if there's a more efficient way of looping through a set of objects that might have some dependencies (child-parent relationship) between them, e.g.:

```
dependencies = [(child1,parent1),(child2,parent2),...]
obj_stack    = [{'id':'child1'},{'id':'child2'},{'id':'parent1'},..]
new_stack    = [{'id':'child1'},{'id':'child3'}]
check_and_add_to_new_stack(obj) # function that decides if an obj should be added to the new stack
```

I want to check each obj_stack and add objs into new_stack under two conditions:

- it has no parent and `check_and_add_to_new_stack(obj)` adds it  (let's assume it does it correctly)
- it has a parent, then add it directly (no need to use the above function)

This means that I need to check if an element has a parent, and then check&add their parent first. If it gets added, then I come back to that element. I am kinda getting stuck on the recursive loop.
Here is the pseudo-code:

```
def check_and_add_to_new_stack(obj,stack):
   if passed_checks(obj):
     return add_to_new_stack(obj,stack)
   return stack

def myFunction(obj_stack, new_stack, dependencies):
  for obj in obj_stack:
    if obj is not in new_stack:
       if obj has parent in dependencies:
         myFunction([parent], new_stack, dependencies) 
       else: # here the original obj should be thrown back into the function
         new_stack += check_and_add_to_new_stack(obj)
  return stack
```

Edit: adding the result that I am expecting and more details:
Let's assume that

```
passed_checks(parent1) = False
passed_checks(parent2) = True
passed_checks(child1) = True
passed_checks(child2) = False
```

The expected result is:

```
myFunction(obj_stack, new_stack, dependencies)
> [{'id':'child1'},{'id':'child3'},{'id':'child2'},{'id':'parent2'}]
```

Even though `passed_checks(child2) = False` it has a `parent2` for which     `passed_checks = True`, so both get added to the resulting set. `child1` was already in `new_stack`. `parent1` did not get added because `passed_checks = False`.

Comment: I'm not quite getting what the end goal is here. What do you want as the result?

Comment: The result should be `new_stack` with elements from `obj_stack` which have either `passed_checks` or have a parent in `dependencies` that has `passed_checks`. I will update my post

Comment: Is there a significance to the order of `new_stack` (as one could imagine from the term `stack`?) Because otherwise this sounds like a graph problem where you need to just pick all ancestors of a given node in a directed acyclic graph (DAG)?

Comment: oh sorry, there isnt a significance. Only in `obj_stack` we loop through the array by order, but if we find that an object has a parent, we want to handle that one first i.e. move it to the front of the 'stack'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for something like this.

- `walk_ancestry` yields node IDs for a given node and all of its parents based on the `parents` dict (which is basically `dict(dependencies)` from your original code)
- `check` is your check function – I just copied your condition there
- The `all_passing` set comprehension iterates over all of our known object names (`obj_stack` in your original code) and uses the built-in `any` function to see if any of the nodes in that node's ancestry pass the `check()` test. If so, it's considered passing.

This could be made faster by caching and memoization, but for small enough graphs, I'm pretty sure this works out alright.

```
def walk_ancestry(parents, node):
    while True:
        yield node
        node = parents.get(node)
        if not node:
            break


def check(node):
    return node in {"parent2", "child1"}


parents = {
    "child1": "parent1",
    "child2": "parent2",
    "parent2": "parent3",
}
all_objects = {
    "parent1",
    "parent2",
    "parent3",
    "child1",
    "child2",
}
all_passing = {
    node
    for node in all_objects
    if any(check(n) for n in walk_ancestry(parents, node))
}
print(all_passing)
```

The output is

```
['parent2', 'child2', 'child1']
```

Comment: what about the `new_stack`? I only want to check those that aren't already in there.

Comment: `if node not in new_stack and any ...` (assuming `new_stack` is just strings)

Comment: great - that seems to work. Let me plug it into my program and see if it works, in case there's something I missed out.

Comment: generator is the perfect fit for this problem, great answer

Comment: @AKX what if I want to modify each node and their parent node rather than just doing a check?

Comment: @user3710760 That sounds like a different question, but either way – you have a way of finding the ancestry of a node, what's preventing you from modifying them?

Comment: @AKX At the moment I only use the ancestry to check something but I am not returning it, so modifying it would require me to return it too. I basically want to check the highest ancestor, if that one passes a check, I set the status to 'ok', then I set all of its children to 'parentOk' (without having to pass the check). If this is quite different, I might have to create a different question.

Comment: @user3710760 You can reverse the return value of  `walk_ancestry`, e.g. `list(walk_ancestry(...))[::-1]`; the first value will be the highest ancestor. You can then check it, and if it passes, continue modifying the objects in the "down-ancestry" chain you now have accordingly.